# close page action popup only when it is clicked again

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

When page action icon is clicked popup is opened. But popup.html will be closed if we click else where. But, can we make popup.html to be opened until page action icon is clicked again.

I searched docs for this but dint find any option to implement this one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

As soon as a popup loses focus, it is closed by design.